# NestJS HTTPModule Get Request with Axios always gets a 400 for https

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

NestJS now uses Axios for requests. When I try a simple Get Request with https it always returns a 400 error.

app.service.ts

```
getGithubDetails(): Observable<AxiosResponse> {
    return this.httpService.get('https://api.github.com/users/bwizrd');
}
```

app.controller.ts

```
@Get()
getGithubDetails(): any {
  return this.appService.getGithubDetails().pipe(
   map(response => response.data)
  )
}
```

A get request to HTTP works fine but to HTTPS it always returns 400. What am I missing?
The same request works fine in Postman.

Comment: What happens if you do the following `curl https://api.github.com/users/bwizrd`? Either you have something between you and the API, or your app needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you, and silly me, should have thought to use curl to check. I get an easier to read error in curl: (Axios error's seem to be a bit vague) curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Comment: You should consider closing this maybe